# Keras NN model isn't compatible with sklearn's votingClassifier

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to ensemble my models and use a votingclassifier from sklearn to get an accuracy score. Right now, my keras model (NN) doesn't fit in the ensemble fitting. Here's my code:

I've tried using skLearn's NN, kerasClassifier. Basically, i've ran out of options.

```
def multiLayerPerceptionModel(nb_epochs, hidden_1, hidden_2, 
learn_rate, batch_size, num_input, num_classes, path_log, X_Train, 
X_Test, Y_Train, Y_Test):
model_RN = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(hidden_1, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(hidden_2, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    ])

model_RN.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model_RN.compile(optimizer=SGD(learn_rate),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model_RN.fit(X_Train, Y_Train, validation_data 
    (X_Test,Y_Test),epochs=nb_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks= 
               [tensorboard])


model_RN.add(Flatten())

   TypeError: Cannot clone object 
   '<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 
   0x11778d400>' (type <class 
   'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>): it does 
   not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 
   'get_params' methods.
```